# Bootstrap navbar disappears when in a div where it should be always visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for the bad title, I didn't really know how to explain it concisely.

I'm trying to make a navbar that only shows up when hovering over an icon that appears only when scrolling upwards and stays visible as long as I have my cursor over it (over the navbar or the icon).
The problem is, I want it to be always visible in the first section of the website.
It works ok when first loading it, but after scrolling down and then returning up when I hover over the navbar and then I move the cursor outside it disappears.

Here's a fiddle so you can take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/kksp9pbu/1/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="menu-trigger" class="hidden-menu trigger"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="main-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
     </nav>
<main>
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="header">
            <h1>The navbar should always be visible here</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="about">
        <div id="about-l"><h3>About</h3></div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="portfolio">
        <div id="about-l"><h3>Portfolio</h3></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS in case you need it:

```
#menu-trigger {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    height: 40px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index:1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-bars{
    color: #fff
}

#main-nav {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 119, 124, 0.46);
    border-bottom: 3px solid #111;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    top:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.hidden-nav {
    top:-75px !important;
}

.trigger {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hidden-menu {
    opacity: 0;
}

#main-nav a:link,
#main-nav a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: 80px;
}

.navbar-nav li {
    padding: 30px 0 0 100px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding: 0 0 5px 0 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover,
.navbar-nav a:active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.navbar-brand {
    transition: color 0.2s ease;
    color: #fff!important;
    font-size: 2em !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
}
.navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #ffb100 !important;
}



/*----HEADER----*/

#header {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #333;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 15%;
}
#header h1 {
    font-size: 2.8em;
    font-weight: 100;
}


/*----ABOUT----*/
#about{
height:100vh;
background-color:#39bebe;
}

#portfolio{
height:100vh;
background-color:#009eee;
}
```

And here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event) {   

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var aboutOffset=$("#about").offset().top;

    if(scroll<=aboutOffset){ // if I haven't reached #about section yet
        $("#main-nav").removeClass("hidden-nav"); 
    } else {
       $("#main-nav").addClass("hidden-nav"); //hide the navbar


         function hideIt(){
             $("#menu-trigger").addClass("hidden-menu"); //hide the trigger
         };

        if (scroll > lastScrollTop){ //scrolling down
            setTimeout(hideIt, 2000);
        } else {
            $("#menu-trigger").removeClass("hidden-menu"); 
        }
        lastScrollTop = scroll;

        $("#menu-trigger, #main-nav").on("mouseover", function(){ //if I hover over the trigger or the navbar
           $("#main-nav").removeClass("hidden-nav"); // I leave the navbar visible
        });

        $("#menu-trigger, #main-nav").on("mouseout", function(){ //if I move the cursor out of the trigger or the navbar
           $("#main-nav").addClass("hidden-nav"); // hide the navbar
        });

    }


}); // END $(window).scroll();


}); //END $(document).ready();
```

Comment: Don't be sorry, just add 'Bootstrap' at the beginning of the question's title and a 'bootstrap' tag at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function that it does something when you do scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) { 
...
}
```

And you have a conditional that when it's false, this sets somthing behaviors.

```
       if(scroll<=aboutOffset){
            $("#main-nav").removeClass("hidden-nav"); 
        } else {
            ...
        }
```

The behavior that it's doing to hide the navbar is this:

```
           $("#menu-trigger, #main-nav").on("mouseout", function(){ 
               $("#main-nav").addClass("hidden-nav");
            });
```

You need to delete this behavior ;-)

**UPDATE**

Or, a better solution would be this:

```
      if(scroll<=aboutOffset){
            $("#main-nav").removeClass("hidden-nav"); 
            $("#menu-trigger, #main-nav").off("mouseout");
      } else {
            ...
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually, I want the navbar to be hidden when scrolling past the header section. 
It's just that after the first time scrolling, if I return up in the header section the "else" piece of jQuery seems to be working even though scroll IS <= aboutOffset, so just the "if" piece should be executed.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Is that a better solution?

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for :)